# Notifications in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how can I show notifications in the windows form applications automatically.

my code here:

```
cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Count(*) from Issue where Return_Date < @Date", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",DateTime.Now);
int NumberOfOverdue = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
cn.Close();

if (NumberOfOverdue > 0)
{
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500, "Library Management System", "There are " + NumberOfOverdue + " overdued book", ToolTipIcon.Warning);
}
```

The code is located int the `Form_Load` and obviously it only triggers after I start the program; but I want the notification to show right after the requirement in the if condition is met automatically.

Comment: Then you should be using something like a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) that check your condition and shows the notification

Comment: "only triggers after I start the program" I don't understand what you are trying to say here. Of course you have to start the program before the Form_Load will run...

Comment: Not clear. When do you want it to come up??? Why not to show it after the program loaded, it is indeed the place that you do not have to press any key

Comment: I think the 2 answerers are kind of hinting at this, but the code will need to be moved out of the Form_Load, and into a method that will be called on a timer, because it sounds like @Nemo want's to monitor the query and when NumberOfOverdue > 0 is true, show the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `SqlDepency` class mentioned by James Dev is a good way, you can also simply use a `Timer` like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private string _connectionString; // set this to your connection string
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new Timer()
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Interval = 2000 // interval in milliseconds
        };

        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using(
                SqlCommand cmd =
                    new SqlCommand("select Count(*) from Issue where Return_Date < @Date", cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                int NumberOfOverdue = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (NumberOfOverdue > 0)
                {
                    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500, "Library Management System",
                                               "There are " + NumberOfOverdue + " overdued book",
                                               ToolTipIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Timer` raises its `Tick` event (approximatly) every 2 seconds (you can choose the time by seting the `Interval` property in milliseconds). In the event handler `_timer_Tick` you can execute your sql request and show the notification if necessary.

I changed your code a little to use `using` statements instead of closing/disposing the objects manually.

Be sure to choose the `Interval` wisely:

- How *immediatly* do you need the notification
- How much network traffic/database load is generated by this request

Answer (score 0):

You have to create own custom event and handler. Once your condition match raised the event and capture at required place.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8b7513/custom-events-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement something like the SQlDependency Class which will allow you to effectively monitor a sql query and if it changes then trigger an event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(v=vs.80).aspx